# How to add NOT NULL constraint on a few columns in one instruction

Tags: sql-server

I have a table without any constraints.

I want to add a NOT NULL constraint to four columns in this table using a single instruction.

I try:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table]
ALTER COLUMN [Colum1] integer NOT NULL, 
             [Column2] integer NOT NULL, 
             [Column3] integer NOT NULL, 
             [Column4] integer NOT NULL;
```

I receive a syntax error.

What is the correct syntax?

Do I have to alter each column in separate instruction?

Comment: [Connect item requesting this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/351514/multiple-alter-column-clauses-in-an-alter-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke too quick (edited out my false statement). You'll have to do it one line at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column1] integer NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column2] integer NOT NULL;
```

You can read more about [ALTER TABLE over at msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the table line by line or you can write the dynamic script to print the statement and execute it

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE
([Colum1] int,
[Colum2] int,
[Colum3] int,
[Colum4] int) 

select 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) + 
    ' ALTER COLUMN ' + c.name + ' int ' + 
    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' END
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where o.type='U' AND O.name = 'EXAMPLE'
order by OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)
```

Result set :

```
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE ALTER COLUMN Colum1 int NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE ALTER COLUMN Colum2 int NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE ALTER COLUMN Colum3 int NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE ALTER COLUMN Colum4 int NOT NULL
```

execute the statement